How to check ephemeral storage that is allocated to EKS node
How to check ephemeral storage that is allocated to EKS node using kubectl command?
I have tried the following: I tried describing the node using kubectl describe node <node-name> which gave lot of info, out of which following is the section related to ephemeral storage.
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         8
  ephemeral-storage:           157274092Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      32042484Ki
  pods:                        58

Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         7
  ephemeral-storage:           142796319300
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      30916084Ki
  pods:                        58

Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests      Limits
  --------                    --------      ------
  cpu                         1105m (15%)   750m (10%)
  memory                      3052Mi (10%)  3486Mi (11%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0             0

With those 3 sections, can anyone help me to find the exact ephemeral-storage that is allocated to node?
[In Allocatable section, I do not see units for ephemeral-stoage (142796319300), what is default unit here]

In the output of your kubectl describe node command, the ephemeral-storage value in the Allocatable section is in bytes.
Capacity (total storage): 157274092Ki, is around 150 GiB.
Allocatable (available storage for workloads): 142796319300 bytes, is about 133 GiB.
So basically, your node has 150 GiB of total ephemeral storage, with ~ 133 GiB available for applications.


How to check ephemeral storage that is allocated to EKS node using kubectl command?

Here's a way:
echo "$(($(kubectl get node <your node name> --output jsonpath='{.status.allocatable.ephemeral-storage}') / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))) GiB"

